# Which kind of attacks could be done on CoAP protocol?

Tags: attacks, iot

I'm a student and I'm studying the security of the CoAP protocol. So, thinking on the attack-surface my thought was about internal attacks (i.e inside the network) and the external attack (i.e. outside the network). Regarding them, considering the scenario without encryption (i.e. without DTLS) there could be done attacks like sniffing packets. So, I was also wondering which kind of other attacks can be done?

Comment: Didn't you say you were studying this topic? So if you just ask what attacks there are, it seems to me as if you expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: I should simulate attack such as spoofing (just to do an example) and then try to make this protocol secure. I don’t want you to do work form me, instead, I just want to have some incipit to start my own researches. I have found a few material about for example the CoAP with the DTLS but I want to learn more and often , ask to people is much more interesting than read papers (that I have just done a bit).